# Drupal Guestbook module text modification

Tags: drupal, module

Just need to change some of the text that the module displays by default on each of my user's individual guestbooks.  The top tab says "My guestbook" and I want to change it to "My comments."  Under all replies it says "Add guestbook entry" and I want that changed to "Add comment."  There are a few more instances like this.  I found language files to switch to different languages like French, but could not find a standard one for English.  The files for this module are here:  http://drupal.org/project/guestbook

(P.S. - Please be a little bit detailed in your reply as I am a novice builder)

Answer (score 0):

Any strings wrapped in t() calls can be overwritten by theming functions in your theme layer.  It looks like the change that you want to make is on line 938 of the current latest 6.x branch:

```
$info[$uid]['title'] = t('My guestbook') . ($unread ? ' ('. $unread .')' : '');
```

You can use the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module to change the text displayed by this string.